# Getting a syntax error in Python for the line: "print len(data), samplerate"

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to work on an Arduino bot whose job will be to just recognise voice commands given only by me. I have a Python code for it. But a line is giving me syntax error. That particular line is a print statement which goes like this `print len(data), samplerate`

```
data, samplerate = sf.read(b) #reading audio file using soundfile library

print len(data), samplerate

x= len(data)
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3, `print` is a function not a statement.

Comment: try print(len(data) + "," + str(samplerate))

Answer (score 0):

If using Python3, then use:

```
print(len(data), samplerate)
```

Instead of:

```
print len(data), samplerate
```